# order by accented characters in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a situation like below:

```
select p.last_name from person p where user_id = 'mprakash' and contains(last_name , 'fré%') > 0
```

Result:

```
FreNormal
Frederic
Frédéric
Frêdéric
```

result comes as above......accented characters always comes last even if i am giving the search condition with using accented characters 'fré%'

Is there something through which we can get result below:

```
Frédéric
Frêdéric
FreNormal
Frederic
```

or if I give search as contains(last_name , 'frê%') > 0 
then result comes as below :

```
Frêdéric
Frédéric
FreNormal
Frederic
```

and if i search as contains(last_name , 'fre%') > 0 then result would be

```
FreNormal
Frederic
Frêdéric
Frédéric
```